# Does Mine die in Akame ga Kill! manga?

Tags: akame-ga-kill

I have watched all the anime episodes and Mine dies in episode 22.

Does she die in the manga as well? I read the last few chapters of the manga where Tatsumi speaks about her like she is not dead.

Comment: I thought I'd add this bit of information: The anime deviates a lot from the manga after Shura (the minister's son) makes his appearance.

Comment: Yes. I read the manga and its a lot different. But they did not have to end the anime so brutally. I hope it does not happen in the manga.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, she didn't die in the manga. However, in order to defeat General Budo, she used all her power in the final attack with Pumpkin and fell in a vegetative state as a result.

This happened in **Chapter 56**:

> [image]
>  [image]

In the last chapter (Chapter 78),

> she's shown to regain consciousness after Tatsumi's return from the battlefield. It is also mentioned that they had children and lived a gentle and peaceful life.

Comment: Good to know. In this anime, when I start liking a character, they get killed.

Comment: Do you think there will be a remake?

Comment: I don't think so: it's quite uncommon for a series to have a remake when it was already given an alternative ending (The only example I know in which this happened is Full Metal Alchemist)